# I am learning the difference between le plus-que-parfait and le conditionnel passé and I am a little confused

Tags: grammaire

As the title states, I am a little confused! I am working on some practice questions and the question asks:

Mettez les verbes entre parenthèses au plus-que-parfait ou au conditionnel passé.

> Si tu (s'amuser) au match de hockey, tu (ne pas entrer) tôt.

I am not sure how I can make sense of that using either tense. I have taken a guess with:

> Si tu t'étais amusé au match de hockey, tu n'aurais pas pu entrer plus tôt.

But that still doesn't make much sense! I would greatly appreciate anyone who could clarify this question for me and help me understand how they got to their answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La concordance des temps implique le plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif dans la proposition subordonnée *« Si tu t'étais amusé »* et le conditionnel passé dans la proposition principale *« tu ne serais pas entré »* ( je pense qu'il doit s'agir plutôt du verbe *rentrer*, soit *« tu ne serais pas **r**entré »*.

La phrase complète est donc :

> Si tu t'étais amusé au match de hockey, tu ne serais pas rentré tôt.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation!!

Comment: @CanadianGirl: You're welcome, glad it helps.